# R "mi" package: mi(...) command throws error

Tags: r, cluster-computing, remote-server, r-mice

I am attempting to do multiple imputation with the "mi" package (v1.0). Due to computing/processing time constraints, I split my code into two files. The first does all of the mi-style preprocessing, and the second actually runs the imputation.

The first file runs without error, but I am including it here for completeness (below is an edited, shorter version of the file):

```
require(mi)

# Load data for multiple imputation
data = as.data.frame(read.delim("for_mi.csv"))
...
# Declare data as missing data frame for MI functions
mdf = missing_data.frame(data)

mdf <- change(mdf, y = "x", what = "type", to = "nonnegative-continuous")
... (many type corrections later) ...
mdf <- change(mdf, y = "y", what = "type", to = "positive-continuous")

# Save pre-processed missing-format data for analysis in r_mi_2.R.
saveRDS(mdf,"preprocessed.rds")
```

The second file is the one that throws the error:

```
require(mi)
# Load output from first file
mdf <- readRDS("preprocessed.rds")

# Note: at this point, mdf loads as a missing_data.frame. 
# MI commands such as show(mdf) function as expected.

# Impute data
imputations <- mi(mdf, n.iter = 30, n.chains = 4, max.minutes = Inf, parallel = TRUE)
```

I get the following output:

```
Chain 1

Chain 1 Iteration 0

Chain 2

Chain 2 Iteration 0

Chain 1 Iteration 1

Chain 3

Chain 3 Iteration 0

Chain 2 Iteration 1

Chain 4

Chain 4 Iteration 0

Chain 3 Iteration 1

Chain 4 Iteration 1

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: cannot open the connection
Calls: mi ... clusterApply -> staticClusterApply -> checkForRemoteErrors
Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '/var/tmp/Rtmp0TqkWn/mi1502972500/pars_1.csv': No such file or directory
Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '/var/tmp/Rtmp0TqkWn/mi1502972500/pars_2.csv': No such file or directory
Execution halted
Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '/var/tmp/Rtmp0TqkWn/mi1502972500/pars_3.csv': No such file or directory
Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '/var/tmp/Rtmp0TqkWn/mi1502972500/pars_4.csv': No such file or directory
```

Other background info:

- I am running the code on a cluster, using 8 processors on a single node. I have also tried running it locally on my computer, with the same result.
- I have tried varying the number of chains, lowering the number of iterations, and setting `parallel = FALSE`, all to no avail.
- I have tried running the code with and without the `options(mc.cores = 4)` line that appears in the mi vignette ([see here, page 4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mi/vignettes/mi_vignette.pdf))
- The mi vignette linked above states that many errors from running `mi` stem from running out of RAM. I'm not sure how to test this, but some info: the starting object `mdf` is 128MB, the per-user server cap on the cluster is 32GB, and the error throws even if I set `parallel=FALSE` or `n.iter=1`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: The error output with `parallel = FALSE` is:

```
Chain 1

Chain 1 Iteration 0

Chain 1 Iteration 1

Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: mi -> mi -> .local -> .mi -> write.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '/var/tmp/Rtmp0TqkWn/mi1502972500/pars_1.csv': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

Comment: It looks as if it is having trouble with multiple cores. What is the text of the error message when `parallel = FALSE`?

Comment: @BenGoodrich Thanks very much for your reply. I get an analogous error with only one core. I can't put line breaks in the comments so I've added the error text with `parallel = FALSE` in the body of the post.

Comment: This appears to be saying that you (as a regular user) do not have permission to write into `/var/tmp/`, which is where it wants to put the temporary directory. There are instructions for how to change this in `help(tempdir)`.